# AngularJS One-Way Binding Issue

Tags: angularjs

I have an object in MainCtrl and pass it to child component with one-way binding. When I change it in child template, changed parent object in MainCtrl. Where is my problem?

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('heroApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl() {
  this.hero = {
    name: 'Spawn'
  };
});
})(window.angular);

(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('heroApp').component('heroDetail', {
  templateUrl: 'heroDetail.html',
  bindings: {
    hero: '<'
  }
});
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <span>Parent Obejct Name: </span>{{ ctrl.hero.name }}
  <br/>
  <hero-detail hero="ctrl.hero"></hero-detail>
</div>

<span>Child Object Name: {{$ctrl.hero.name}}</span>
<br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.hero.name" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not your problem. Objects are always passed by reference. No matter, one-way or two-way binding are used. To avoid it, you must do copy of object in child component

> Note however, that both parent and component scope reference the same
>   object, so if you are changing object properties or array elements in
>   the component, the parent will still reflect that change. The general
>   rule should therefore be to never change an object or array property
>   in the component scope

[Understanding Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

[One-way data-binding in Angular 1.5](https://toddmotto.com/one-way-data-binding-in-angular-1-5/)